# Visual Studio not reading from Environmental Variables

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

When I call the `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY_1')` in Visual Studio it returns None.

I am trying to hide my Django SECRET_KEY by storing it as an Environmental variable. I also noticed if I run the exact command to test in pycharm, it returns the exact key but doing the same under visual studio code which I'm using returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `python-decouple==3.3`.

Steps:

1. Install: `pip3 install python-decouple==3.3`
2. Import: `from decouple import config`
3. Use it: `SECRET_KEY_1 = config('SECRET_KEY_1')`

Make sure you have `SECRET_KEY_1` variable in `.env` file

Comment: Yeah that was what I ended up using. I searched for an alternative and saw it